# getClass() on refrance of an anonymous interface in java gives class name

Tags: java, interface

In my below mentioned situation, I am getting two different o/p while using   instanceof and getClass() on common refrance.
I have a Interface Foo.

```
public interface Foo {  void dispaly();}
```

giving body to `display();` in side another class using anonymous block technique.

```
public  class ClassWithMainMethod {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Foo obj = new Foo(){
        @Override
        public void dispaly() {System.out.println("msg");}      
    };
 System.out.println(obj instanceof Foo); // result: true
 System.out.println(obj.getClass());//result com.ClassWithMainMethod$1
 obj.dispaly(); // result: msg  
}}
```

Now at `obj.getClass`, why I am not getting com.Foo as an o/p.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This block of code

```
 Foo obj = new Foo(){
     @Override
     public void dispaly() {System.out.println("msg");}      
 };
```

creates an anonymous class that implements the interface `Foo`. The resulting anonymous class is not identical to `com.Foo` and doesn't have it's name. During compilation, anonymous classes are given names, depending of their containing class. The format is `<containing class name>$<identifier>`.

Your containing class is `ClassWithMainMethod` and your class is the first anonymous class inside, so the resulting name is `com.ClassWithMainMethod$1`. Since this class implements `com.Foo`, the `instanceOf` operator returns `true` and you are able to invoke the `display()` method.

Comment: ok, But i checked getClass() on ClassWithMainMethod's object also, that time i got result com.ClassWithMainMethod. which didn't included $1.

Comment: @deepeshkumar That's because `getClass()` returns the runtime class of the object you are invoking it on. `obj.getClass()` is invoked on an instance of your anonymous class and returns it's name. If you call only `getClass()`, it will invoke it on the current object, and will return the current object's class  name, in your case - `ClassWithMainMethod`. You have to keep in mind that the `ClassWithMainMethod` and your anonymous class are 2 very different classes.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this method to determine the super class or super interface of the anonymous class:

```
static Class<?> getAnonymousClass(Object o){
    Class<?> superClass=o.getClass().getSuperclass();
    Class<?>[] superInterface=o.getClass().getInterfaces();

    return superClass!=java.lang.Object.class?superClass:
        superInterface.length>0?superInterface[0]:java.lang.Object.class;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

getClass() always returns runtime class, which is com.ClassWithMainMethod$1

Comment: That is not true, just put below two lines anywhere in main method and run.         
    ` String s = new String();
      System.out.println(s.getClass()); '
this time you will get class java.lang.String but you are in other class

Comment: here we are talking about interface, and String class is not an interface, i hope you got my point.